# No se muestra una imagen en dispositivos apple

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, iphone

tengo este problema, diseñe una pagina que tiene tres imagenes sobre puestas de portada, dos con background de un div y otra como img y estan animadas ambas. Esto se muestra bien desde cualquier laptop y dispositivos android, pero al ingresar desde un dispositivo Iphone la imagen de fondo que es la del div "slider-area" no se muestra.

adjunto el codigo html de la portada:

```
<div class="slider-area position-relative">
        <div class="slider-active">
            <!-- Single Slider -->
            <div class="single-slider slider-height d-flex align-items-center">
                <div class="logo-bg">
                    <img src="./assets/img/logo/logo-white.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="cover">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Adjunto el bloque de codigo del css tambien:

```
.slider-area {
  margin-top: -1px;
  background-image: url(../img/elements/sky.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  animation: moveBackground 20s linear infinite alternate;
  min-height: 100vh !important;
}

@keyframes moveBackground {
  from {
    background-position: left;
  }
  to {
    background-position: right;
  }
}

.logo-bg {
  width: 100%;
}

.logo-bg img {
  left: 50%;
  transform: scale(1, 1.1) translate(-50%, 10%);
  position: fixed;
  animation: fadeInLogo 5s both;
}

@keyframes fadeInLogo {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    top: 60%;
    width: 100px;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 10%;
    width: 300px;
  }
}

.cover {
  background-image: url(../img/elements/cover-bg.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  min-height: 100vh !important;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```